# Synergy between mac and pc change mac hotkeys

Tags: macos, applescript

[Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/) is a program that enables you to use the same mouse and keyboard in two computers. I have a PC and mac connected directly with an Ethernet cable therefore the connection is great and it seems as if there is only one computer.

I am developing an iPad application and the only software that I have found that supports iwebkit for CSS is Expresso. I use that to edit my CSS files in the mac and I use dream weaver on my PC to edit PHP, HTML and JavaScript files. The only problem is that I am constantly using both computers to develop the application and its very frustrating using different shortcut keys for each computer. It would be very nice if I could use the same hot-keys on both computers.

So far I have tried:

1. Changing the modifier keys in the keyboard section under system preferences in the mac. That works but just with the keyboard from the mac not with the keyboard that I am using with synergy that controls both computers.
2. Creating applescripts that what they do is to send a shortcut key then compiling them and saving them as an application. After they are saved as an application I go to system preferences and try to run them with a different shortcut key. when I create that shortcut key system preferences crashes and closes without saving the changes.
3. Creating shortcut keys in synergy which it works but only in one computer. Synergy will always send the same keystroke regardless on which computer you are using.
4. Lastly I have tried looking for "IronAHK" which in a lot of posts people say it modifies the mac hotkeys but I have not been able to find it for the mac.

Is there a way to have the same universal access keys across my machines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the mac I use KeyRemap4MacBook.  It is pretty good for being free.

That said, consider using different source editors so that you can code only on one system.  This will make your life a *ton* easier.  Dreamweaver is not necessarily the best.  Visual Studio is pretty good on Javascript, CSS, and HTML, and their express versions are free.

If all you need is syntax highlighting EditPlus is great on the PC and will work on all languages you mentioned.  If you need to stay on a mac then TextWrangler is great as a basic source editor.  Both have free trials.  Good luck!

Comment: That program is great and it was exactly what I thought I needed. It swaps the keys perfectly fine but just from the keyboard from the mac. Maybe synergy sends the keys directly and that's why the keys don't get swiped. Maybe I need to get a good program for the pc that supports css for the iphone and iPad because when developing the web based application for the iPad I have to use a lot of animations with key frames that are not supported with dream weaver nor visual studio. the only reason why I am using the mac is because I need the intellisense for those animations.

Comment: I've just tried KeyRemap4MacBook and it doesn't play nice with Synergy (PC as server, Mac as client).  Events don't seem to fire, presumably because of the way the Synergy client is emulating the key presses?  If I use the keyboard directly connected to the Mac it works fine however.

Answer (score 11):

THe following article was very helpful for me (working from a Mac, controlling a PC):

http://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-properly-map-keyboard-between-mac-and-pc-when-share-mouses-with-synergy/

**Step 1: Configure Server**

[image: Step 1]

**Step 2: Double-click on the PC (or Mac if the Server is a PC)**

[image]

**Step 3: Toggle the key Ctrl and Super to mirror each other**

[image]

Comment: As mine! Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

When adding a new computer in synergy you can change command and control keys. Here is an example in windows. I was not able to find it because synergy place this in a location where I never thought I could find it.

Now I can use control + c to copy files both in the mac and in the pc and most of the command such as control + a to select everything etc. To fix the other issues so that I can use 'home' to go to the beginning of the line for example I use the program provided by Evan Moran which was the first answer in this post.

[image]

Comment: i always get "looking for peers" on my mac ... have any idea for my problem?

Comment: How does it help when I switch Ctrl and Alt? My Command key is on the Windows key ^^